# Laravel restrict values based upon role

Tags: php, laravel

My users can have one of the following roles: Admin, Publisher & Creator. When they are Publisher or Creator, they can only access Posts where X customer was assigned to them.

Usually I would do the following to get all the posts:

```
$posts = \App\Models\Posts::with('Customer')->all();
```

But now I need to filter according to the role. I'm trying to avoid having several conditions (like the sample below), because in the future I might add more code logic:

```
if (Admin)
 // Get all
else
 // Get all where customer is assigned to user
```

Note: The Admin users does not need to be assigned to any Customer, they  have access to everything.

I was hoping Laravel would be able to understand a custom function to be used in Eloquent, like:

```
$posts = \App\Models\Posts::with('Customer')->filtered()->all();
```

The filtered function must look into the role & the Customer Id, something like:

```
public function filtered($userId, $customerId)
{
    // Has always access to everything
    if (\App\User::isAdmin())
        return true;

    return \App\Models\UsersCustomers::where('user_id', $userId)
        ->where('customer_id', $customerId)
        ->exists();
}
```

I'm aware of Scopes https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent#query-scopes but I'm having a hard time finding out how to implement it correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved**.

Like the document states https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent#query-scopes

> Global scopes allow you to add constraints to all queries for a given
> model

The problem with Global Scopes, at least in my case, is that if there are Posts assigned to some Customer the X user has access to but later the access is removed it will return the Page 404.

So instead of Global Scopes, I end up using the Local Scopes https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent#local-scopes

> Local scopes allow you to define common sets of constraints that you
> may easily re-use throughout your application. For example, you may
> need to frequently retrieve all users that are considered "popular"

In the Customers model class I created the following function:

```
public function scopeHasAccess($query)
{
    // Access to everything
    if (\App\User::isAdmin())
        return $query;

    $userId = \Auth::id();    
    
    return $query->whereRaw("(SELECT COUNT(id) FROM users_customers WHERE user_id = '{$userId}' AND customer_id = customers.id) > 0");
}
```

This allows me to use the function like this `\App\Models\Customers::where('type', $type)->hasAccess()->get();` but also in a more complex query:

```
\App\Models\Posts::with('Related')
    ->with('Customer')
    ->where('types', $types)
    ->whereHas('Customer', function($query)
    {
        $query->hasAccess();
    });
    ->get();
```

Comment: Did you have look at model policies? Feels like sort of reinventing model policies, I might be wrong though.

Comment: @user3532758 I wasn't aware of policies, but after a quick read, it seems that would be also an good approach.